# Can we bring chatter in left sidebar of home page?

Tags: community, chatter, home-page-component

I want to customize my home page and want to display chatter in left sidebar of home page as well as dashboard description on right hand side of Home page, how can I achieve this?

**update:**
I don't want to make another chatter functionality, I just want that the chatter messages should be displayed in left side bar of Home page designed by me. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with point&click customizations, you will have to go the Visualforce way to achieve this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Not sure how this isn't an adequate answer to the question "Can it be done and how can we achieve this"? Yes it can be done, not with point&click, but with Visualforce.

Comment: Don't even think you can pull that off with visualforce .. soon maybe with lightning components.

Comment: RObin your answer needs to be ellaborate just telling Visualforce wont help user .Provide a code snippet or logic that helps user

Comment: I was almost close to it using customization. Some way might be possible please try and tell me if you can.

Comment: Mohith Shrivastava.. Do you have any solution for doing it using customization process, because if I''ll go for Visualforce pages but in that case I can design UI only and for the functioning of chatter and dashboard i'll have to write controller, my question is why to make another chatter and dashboard using coding when it is already provided by Salesforce.